# Autoboxing Question

Tags: java, autoboxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapper class and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/wrapper-class-and-operator)

Saw this code in a website when i was learning about autoboxing..

```
Integer i1 = 1;  
Integer i2 = 1;  
// true 
System.out.println(i1 == i2);  


Integer i3 = -200;  
Integer i4 = -200;  
// false
System.out.println(i3 == i4);
```

I can understand why the 2nd comparison gives false (its comparing references). But why is it giving true for the first one ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out..  answers there  were more explanatory! :)

Comment: answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/wrapper-objects-share-the-same-address-space-only-within-the-value-127/5117175#5117175

Comment: Perhaps you could have asked the person who wrote it what it meant. e.g. ask the question in a comment. ;)  http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/incorrect-core-java-interview-answers.html#comments

Comment: You see, i was seeing this : http://java.dzone.com/articles/incorrect-core-java-interview for which i had to "register" for posting comments..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the first several `Integer` objects (from -128 to 127, inclusive, to be precise) are cached and reused by the JVM, so `i1` and `i2` are references to the same physical object.

This is also true to `Long`, `Short` and `Byte` btw. See [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue102.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Could you explain this further?  If the first several Integer objects are cached, why aren't i3 and i4 pointing to the same physical object?

Comment: @Kyle, extended my answer with more details and an article reference.

Comment: are other objects of classes like Strings cached (cos i just tried "a" == "a" .. and it gave me true)? can u point me to a article or something related to caching?

Comment: @raj: That's a case of *string literals* being interned. Again, see the specification - I can find a section number if you want.

Comment: Thanks.. I just finished downloading that..

Answer (score 3):

Boxing is guaranteed to use the same cached objects for a range of values.

Beyond that the JVM *can* use a larger cache, but it's not guaranteed. From the JLS [section 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Comment: The Integer documentation [says](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) that frequently requested values may be cached.

Comment: @Brian: Indeed. It's just not guaranteed *apart from* the values in the spec.

Comment: +1: `Long` also has a cache for values -128 to 127 in the Sun/Oracle JVM even though it is not mentioned.