# Java wrapper classes object equality - odd behaviour

Tags: java, object, wrapper, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapper class and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/wrapper-class-and-operator)

It seems as if object equality operator for wrapper classes produces different results depending on whether the wrapped value is in byte range or not. Here is a code snippet to demonstrate this behavior:

```
System.out.println("smaller than byte");

Integer i1 = 1;

Integer i2 = 1;

if (i1 == i2) System.out.println("same");

if (i1 != i2) System.out.println("not same");

System.out.println("larger than byte");

Integer i3 = 128;

Integer i4 = 128;

if (i3 == i4) System.out.println("same");

if (i3 != i4) System.out.println("not same");
```

produces the following output:

```
smaller than byte

same

larger than byte 

not same
```

Note: I got this output on HotSpot (build 1.6.0_24-b07) on linux. Same happens for Long and probably Short (haven't tested it though).

Note: Same output on other HotSpot builds under linux
Can anyone explain it?

---

Small edit, just to make it slightly more interesting:

Adding

```
if (i3 <= i4 && i3 >= i4) System.out.println("same after all...");
```

in the end, prints "`same after all...`".

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. The JVM will "cache" and reuse `Integer` instances when autoboxing small values.

See Java Language Specification [Section 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190697):

> *If the value p being boxed is `true`, `false`, a byte, a char in the range `\u0000` to `\u007f`, **or an int or short number between -128 and 127**, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.*

When comparing `Integer`s using `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` the values are un-boxed as opposed to `!=` and `==`.

Comment: thanks - I'm currently learning for SCJP and found a similar example in the official study guide - the explanation the authors give for this behavior is different ( and obviously wrong!)

Comment: @maciek: really? Could you tell us which source you think is wrong or even give a short excerpt?

Comment: well, i haven't read it carefully enough as it seems. it actually says further in the text that this behavior applies to Short and Integer only between -128 and 127. my fault

Answer (score 2):

Integers between -127 and 127 are 'cached', so they return same reference, which means i1 and i2 point to same object.