# Compare two Integer: why is == true?

Tags: java, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapper class and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/wrapper-class-and-operator)

Hi when I am comparing Integer with == I have some problem so 
can you explain me why second test is success too ?

```
@Test
public void integerTest() {
    Integer prvni = 127;
    Integer druhy = 127;
    Integer treti = 128;
    Integer ctvrty = 128;

    assertTrue(prvni == druhy);
    assertTrue(treti != ctvrty);

}
```

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/wrapper-objects-share-the-same-address-space-only-within-the-value-127

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `==` to compare Objects, you're actually comparing the references. I.e., the reason both assertions are true is because the `prvni` and `druhy` *refer to the same object* while `treti` and `ctvrty` does not.

This is because the JVM *caches* `Integer` objects in the range -128 to 127, and reuses cached objects when autoboxing the values.

Unless you switch to `int` instead, you could go through [`prvni.intValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue%28%29) or use `prvni.equals(...)` instead.

Comment: If you change the 128 to a number in that range (e.g. 125) the code works as expected.

Why doesn't java cache the numbers on runtime?

Comment: The range is wrong-- it's -128 to 127.

Comment: @leifg: Java uses an array as the backing store for the `Integer` cache. Arrays cannot be resized at runtime, nor can they be used for sparse structures (i.e., to cache values far apart with no cached objects in between). A `Hashtable` or similar could be used, but those are only allowed to have `Object` keys, which means you'd have to use `Integer` objects (rather than `int` primitives) as the keys, which just brings up the whole problem again! So the only option is to use an array with a sensible range.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 1.5, [some of the wrapper classes have introduced a cache](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching). For `Integer`, any number between -128 and 127 inclusive fell in the cache. Other values needed to be wrapped in a `new Integer` every time.

The `==` operator compares references. Since the cached Integer values for 127 are in fact the very same object, `==` returns `true`. For the 128 `Integer` objects, they are two different objects and do not have the same reference equality.

There are two more reliable ways you can compare for equality:

```
if (treti.equals(ctvrty)) { /* do something */ }
```

or:

```
if (treti.compareTo(ctvrty) == 0) { /* do something */ }
```

The latter comparison takes advantage of the fact that `Integer` implements the `Comparable` interface and thus defines a `compareTo` method which returns a negative value if the first object is "less than" the second, a positive value if the first object is "greater than" the second, and zero if the objects compare equal.

Answer (score -2):

The autoboxing feature creates a new instance for every object.

try this:

```
int treti = 128;
int ctvrty = 128;
```

Comment: -1: Doesn't explain why the 127 case works and doesn't completely answer the question. Look into the wrapper class caching.