# Why does System.out.println('a' == 97.0) give true

Tags: java

I know that '==' operator checks for if they exists in the same memory location in Java, but why, whrn I am comparing `char` and `double` data types, Java is giving me `true`? Are they not different data types? And why it is not giving me a compile-time error, because according to the docs:

> If we apply == for object types then, there should be compatibility between
> arguments types (either child to parent or parent to child or same type).
> Otherwise, we will get a compile-time error.

Comment: *"I know that '==' operator ches for if they exists in the same memory location in Java..."* Not with primitives. For numeric types (like `double` and `char`), [see this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095293/how-does-compare-memory-location/15226165?r=SearchResults&s=15%7C33.4456#15226165

Comment: As an aside, your last question doesn't follow from the quoted text. A run-time exception is not the same thing as a compile-time error.

Comment: Neither `char` nor `double` is an object type, so your quote is irrelevant. You will need to read about this situation elsewhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that '==' operator ches for if they exists in the same memory location in Java...

Not with primitives, only with reference types (objects). There are three sections for `==`/`!=` in the Java Language Specificiation:

1. [Numerical Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)
2. [Boolean Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2)
3. [Reference Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3)

`double` and `char` are both numeric, so you refer to [the first one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1). It describes the steps it goes through ([conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) if necessary, [promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) if necessary, [value set conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.13) if necessary, [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) if necessary) to take a `char` and a `double` and convert them so it can compare them numerically.

Comment: *(I couldn't find a good previous question on this, which surprised me greatly, so I gave up looking and posted a CW answer.)*

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `char` and `double` are primitives, which are compared by value using `==`, not by memory location, that is only for objects (reference types).

When you do `'a' == 97.0`, it is a comparison between `char` and `double`. `char` is an unsigned integer, and when compared to a `double`, `char` undergoes a widening conversion to `double`. The character `'a'` corresponds to the numeric value 97, so when converted to `double`, it is 97.0. And given `97.0 == 97.0` is true, that is the result of the expression.

See also in the Java Language Specification:

- [15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)

  > If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or
  > one is of numeric type and the other is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to
  > numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands
  > ([§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)).
- [5.6. Numeric Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)

  > Numeric promotion determines the promoted type of all the expressions
  > in a numeric context. The promoted type is chosen such that each
  > expression can be converted to the promoted type, and, in the case of
  > an arithmetic operation, the operation is defined for values of the
  > promoted type. The order of expressions in a numeric context is not
  > significant for numeric promotion. The rules are as follows:
  >
  > 1. [..]
  > 2. Next, widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) and narrowing primitive conversion ([§5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)) are applied to some expressions,
  >    according to the following rules:
  >
  >    - If any expression is of type double, then the promoted type is double, and other expressions that are not of type double undergo
  >      widening primitive conversion to double.