# Why same integer value have different memory address in Java?

Tags: java, memory

Today is my first time to try Java language. When I try this code, I feel very strange:

```
int a =500;
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(500));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(500));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a));
```

All of these results is different. But when I changed 500 to 50, It become the same result.

Why is it?

Comment: @Tichodroma How is this a duplicate? There is no String involved nor an Integer... But maybe I don't understand this thing well enough, because I am confused by the result of the code. (And I can confirm it)

Comment: @brimborium Did you read the accepted answer to the question? Look for `500`.

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes. I get that this is closely linked... But I think this question is very well stated and is still **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> But when I changed 500 to 50, It become the same result.

Autoboxing caches the conversion of primitives to Object. Small values get the same object, larger values do not.

Note: while values between -128 and 127 are always cached, Higher values can be cached depending on command line settings. See the source for `Integer` for more details.

This is also called a [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

---

You can set the maximum size of the Integer cache with

```
-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=NNNN
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=NNNN
-XX:+AggressiveOpts  // sets it higher depending on the version e.g. 10000
```

http://martykopka.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/all-about-java-integer-cache.html

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue191.html

> I feel very strange

I know what you mean reading this question. ;)

Comment: I didn't know about the command line setting; can you elaborate? I'm only seeing the `private static class IntegerCache` used by `Integer.valueOf(int i)`, which is what reminded me of _memoization_.

Comment: @trashgod There is at least three options which alter the upper limit of the Integer cache. Added examples and links.

Comment: @trashgod The Flyweight Pattern and Memorisation have similarities. Both try to reduce work by using a cache.

Comment: Ok, I see it now: `IntegerCache` is the data structure and `valueOf()` is the static factory that recycles cached instances. +1 from earlier, BTW.

Comment: It doesn't recycle the objects as such because they never go back. It just hands them out. It can do this because they are immutable.

Answer (score 4):

It caches the `int` value  -128 and 127 (inclusive), So it will refer to same instance in memory within that range

When you pass primitive value to  (here `10`)

```
System.identityHashCode(10);
```

It autoboxes it to `Integer` object and it inturns uses [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) method of Integer class for conversion

**For Example**

```
Integer a = 10;
```

will get converted in to internally it uses [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

```
1:   invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

[`Integer.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) which has got the cache implementation

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
    else
        return new Integer(i);
}
```

so if you pass the value from -128 to 127(inclusive) it will use the cached version as you can see from

```
    if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
```

---

**See Also**

- [Integer wrapper class and == operator - where is behavior specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/integer-wrapper-class-and-operator-where-is-behavior-specified)

Comment: +1 See also [_memoization_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: @trashgod I would call it a Flyweight Pattern as objects are cached to reduce object creation overhead, rather than results memorized to reduce calculation times.