# Why are 2 Long variables not equal with == operator in Java?

Tags: java, equals, long-integer

I got a very strange problem when I'm trying to compare 2 Long variables, they always show false and I can be sure they have the same number value by debugging in Eclipse:

```
if (user.getId() == admin.getId()) {
    return true; // Always enter here
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Both of above 2 return values are object-type Long, which confused me. And to verify that I wrote a main method like this:

```
Long id1 = 123L;
Long id2 = 123L;

System.out.println(id1 == id2);
```

It prints true.

So can somebody give me ideas?. I've been working in Java Development for 3 years but cannot explain this case.

Comment: It depends on the size of the Long. Smaller Longs and Integers are interred and are truly identical objects, but longer ones are not, and for these you will need to use `.equals(...)` or unbox them.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`==` compares references, `.equals()` compares values. These two Longs are objects, therefore object references are compared when using `==` operator.

However, note that in `Long id1 = 123L;` literal value `123L` will be auto-boxed into a `Long` object using `Long.valueOf(String)`, and internally, this process will use a LongCache which has a `[-128,127]` range, and 123 is in this range, which means, that the long object is cached, and these two are actually the same objects.

Comment: in my case, the returned ID value is 16 which is not exceeded to its range.

Comment: yeah，but those Longs may not created by Long.valueOf(),meigh be new Long(12),so,they are different objects.

Comment: Runtime implementations are guaranteed to cache `Integer` values -128..127.  Values outside that range, or of any other numeric type (e.g. `Long`), may be cached if the runtime happens to notice that doing so would be advantageous in a particular case, but the spec says nothing about what advantageous cases the runtime will or will not recognize.

Answer (score 9):

because `==` compares reference value, and smaller [long values are cached](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.valueOf%28long%29)

```
 public static Long  valueOf(long l) {
     final int offset = 128;
     if (l >= -128 && l <= 127) { // will cache
         return LongCache.cache[(int)l + offset];
     }
     return new Long(l);
 }
```

so it works for smaller long values

**Also See**

- [Integer wrapper class and == operator - where is behavior specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/integer-wrapper-class-and-operator-where-is-behavior-specified)

Comment: But user.getId() only returns 16 in my case, I think it is small enough. How to explain it?

Answer (score 3):

Stuck on an issue for 4 hours because of the use of `==` ... The comparison was ok on `Long < 128` but ko on greater values.

Generally it's not a good idea to use `==` to compare `Objects`, use `.equals()` as much as possible ! Keep `==, >, <, <= etc.` for primitives.

Comment: primitives and enums