# Why does comparing two equal Float values with == returns false

Tags: java

If I have

```
    Float f1 = 5.25f;
    Float f2 = 5.25f;
```

Then

```
    f1 == f2
```

is false. Though

```
    f1.equals(f2);
```

is true. Why is it so, I thought that if the unboxing is executed, then f1 == f2 should compare

```
f1.floatValue() == f2.floatValue();
```

the same as

```
f1.equals(f2);
```

should do. What is wrong?

**UPDATE:** No I see the answer, because Java compares references for Float objects too. I asked the question because I had

```
    Long l = 15l;
    Long l2 = 15l;
```

But the

```
    System.out.println(l == l2);
```

output was

```
    true
```

So I was misleaded, and thought that numeric type objects are compared by value when using ==. 
But I found, that comparison of small long values will return true, because [small long values are cached!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19485826/1101989)

Comment: because they are objects and `==` compares references.

Comment: @njzk2 sounds like an answer to me :)

Comment: There is no reason to unbox, as none of the arguments calls for a primitive comparison

Comment: For the same reason that comparing two equal String values with == can return false. Since they are both Float, no unboxing occurs. Why would it?

Comment: And why would u use `Float` class instead of primitive `float` data-type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating and comparing floating points in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896013/manipulating-and-comparing-floating-points-in-java)

Comment: Even if they were `float` and not `Float`, you generally should not use `==` to compare, unless you really, truly expect them to be *exactly* equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f1` and `f2` are objects.

`==` compares references.

There is no reason to unbox, as none of the arguments calls for a primitive comparison

If you compare `f1 == 3.0f` or `f1 == f2.floatValue()`, there will be unboxing, because one og the operands is a primitive.

Comment: also have to take into account epsilon when comparing floating point numbers in almost any language

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

- `==` compares the references.
- `.equals` compares the values.

The same is true for [String(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) and all other objects.